# Create multiple http calls from http interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, interceptor

Is it possible to make an http request before an ongoing http request completes (*Eg: fetching a token/refresh token from server before ongoing request completes*).

I have implemented the following using Angular 5 `httpInterceptor` but I am unable to do it using Angular 7.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return Observable.fromPromise(this.handleAccess(request, next))
              .map(response => {
                console.log(response);

                this.globalService.showOrShowloadingModel("hide");
                return response;
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log("HTTP error", error);  
                return Observable.of(error);
              });
}

private async handleAccess(request: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
        //logic to fire token api
        await this.globalService.validateAccessToken();
        return next.handle(request).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Angular 5 & 7 have the exact same principle for interceptors. If you did it in 5, you also did it in 7.

Comment: I have added the code done in Angular 5, It gives an error at return Observable.fromPromise

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ForkJoin. You can call multiple Http Requests by using ForkJoin.
First you have to import forkJOin from rxJs.
Then
    `forkJoin(
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request One', 2000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Two', 1000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Three', 3000)
    )`

it will call these three request at a same time

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use it inside HttpInterceptor